# How to put named imports into a namespace?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I would like to access some imports like `Rx.Observable` or `Rx.Subject`. Look at the following:

```
import {Observable, Subject} from 'rxjs'
```

This is valid but they will be imported into the current scope instead of a namespace.

```
import {Observable, Subject} as Rx from 'rxjs'
```

This is not valid.

```
import * as Rx from 'rxjs'
```

This is valid but it imports everything and can make file size larger.

Is there a solution?

Comment: _“This is valid but it imports everything and can make file size larger.”_ — Imports don’t affect the file size based on what part you import. You still have to download the entire file.

Comment: @SebastianSimon he's talking about the file size of the bundled code, and yes it does make a huge difference, especially when dealing with large libraries like `rxjs`. I implore you to read about [tree-shaking](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en#tree-shaking), which works based on analysis of what is imported. Using `*` instead of specific identifiers prevents static analysis from tree-shaking properly.

Comment: why not make a dynamic import? if worried about the file size?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts No, using namespace imports does *not* prevent tree-shaking, unless you pass the object to things that cannot be easily analysed.

Comment: @Bergi the point is that given the choice between the two statements, and assuming the module has no side-effects, the named import is _more likely_ and _more easily_ able to be tree-shaked. If nothing else, it will reduce your compile time.

Comment: Even in the absence of conflict, I am still uneasy with function names only a few characters long, as they are mostly devoid of meaning, and force the reader to rely heavily on context to understand the code. The former syntax `Observer.of(...)`, for example, is much more meaningful than the newer `of(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're okay with having an extra JavaScript file to fulfill this purpose, I would suggest adding a new file with the line

```
export { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
```

If that was in `./namespaces/rx.js`, then in your existing file you could write

```
import * as Rx from './namespaces/rx.js';
```

which allows you to have a namespace with only the exports you wanted to target.

Comment: I wonder how common this work-around is, and why ecmascript designers didn't create a nicer syntax for this use case

Comment: @Thomas it's not a common pattern to have imports as part of a namespace in my experience. It's more typical to do things like `import { Observable as RxObservable, Subject as RxSubject } from 'rxjs';` if the names conflict with imports from another library. If there's no name conflicts with the imports, then there's not really a reason to create a namespace.